# How to send UDP from an android app over WIFI/4G

Tags: android, kotlin, udp

I have this code.based on various stackoverflow answers:

```
Thread(Runnable {

                Log.i("THREAD --->", "started")
                try {
                    serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(testServer)
                } catch (e: UnknownHostException) {
                    e.printStackTrace()
                }
                try {
                    ds = DatagramSocket()
                } catch (e: SocketException) {
                    e.printStackTrace()
                }

                dp = DatagramPacket(udpMsg.toByteArray(), udpMsg.length, serverAddr, 7501)

                try {
                    ds!!.send(dp)
                } catch (e: IOException) {
                    e.printStackTrace()
                }

                ds!!.close()
             Thread.sleep(1000)

            }).start()
```

The programming language is Kotlin.

I want to send the data to an UDP server over 4G/wifi. However - I am unable to do so. The packet, according to the server logs.

If however, i try to send the same data via my Oracle cloud - it will immediately arrive.
I have allowed:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" android:maxSdkVersion="32" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_VIDEO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

in `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

I read that some service provider may cause a problem with UDP. However, I am unable to find any reliable answer. Please help.